# SQL Server Error, 'Keyword not supported 'datasource'

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, datasource

I'm currently trying to INSERT some values into a datasource, then display them on another page using the DataList control. However, after some testing and experimentation, I've found that the error comes from the very beginning.

Here is the code I have bound to my button.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Page.Validate("vld2");
    SendMail();
    lblMsgSend.Visible = true;
    txtPhone.Text = "";
    txtEmail.Text = "";
    txtName.Text = "";
    txtComment.Text = "";

    //SQL Server Database
    SqlConnection conn; //manages connection to database
    SqlCommand cmd; //manages the SQL statements
    string strInsert; //SQL INSERT Statement
        try
        {
            //create a connection object
            conn = new SqlConnection("DataSource=localhost\\sqlexpress;" +
                                     "Initial Catalog=RionServer;" +
                                     "Integrated Security=True;");
            //Build the SQL INSERT Document
            strInsert = "INSERT INTO CommentsAdmin (Name,Phone,Email,Comments)"
                + "VALUES(@Name,@Phone,@Email,@Comments);";
            //associate the INSERT statement with the connection
            cmd = new SqlCommand(strInsert, conn);
            //TELL the SqlCommand WHERE to get the data from
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", txtName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", txtPhone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", txtEmail);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comments", txtComment);
            //open the connection
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            //run the SQL statement
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //close connection
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            //display status message on the webpage
            lblMsgSend.Text = "Thank you for the comment! Please hit the 'Return to Main Page' to return to the Main Page!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsgSend.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Here is the image of my webpage and the error it displays.

[image: SQL Server Error. Keyword 'datasource' not supported]

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName);. I think you missing `@`.

Comment: -1 Shree what are you talking about.. the OP clearly states in his title what his issue is .. not sure where you came up with something that he clearly has in his code `Key Word DataSource` not supported a space clearly fixes his problem..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your connection string, it should be "Data Source", not "DataSource". Just add a space.

Comment: Okay so that worked. However, I've got a new error.
"No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type."

Comment: When you're setting your parameter values from the textboxes, you should be using the `.Text` property. Like this: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", txtName.Text);`

Comment: Hah, just my good ol' stupidity at work! Such lil details missed. Thanks for the help!